# jQuery issue with one of my divs

Tags: jquery, html

EDIT: I got my .panel div to not run up through the whole page by adding clear:both to the CSS. Thanks guys for your help and suggestions.

Please check out the little project I'm working on to practice my html/css/js at http://opmet.net

I'm having an issue with the mouse hover that triggers the footer animation. I only want to toggle the footer when I hover in/out of #opmetAbout or #panel. If you look at the HTML you see the .panel class on a div around #opmetAbout and #panel gives desired hover effect.

For whatever reason though, the panel effect is triggered when you hover over the middle padding in-between #right (Sleep Time) & #left (Wake time).

Can somebody please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

PS I know the actual sleep/wake time calculators have no functionality yet. Any suggestions as to how to do that with js are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the .panel div I wrapped around my #footer and #panel ran up through the whole page. Any empty space between divs on the page would trigger the jQuery. To prevent the .panel  div from running up through the page I made the CSS like this. Thanks for all your help and suggestions that lead me to this conclusion.

```
.panel {
     clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
<body> <!-- this tag was in the wrong place.... fix that! -->
<h1 id="header2"><div>Tempo</div></h1>
<div id="floatholders">  <!-- this tag is new -->
  <div id="left" ><br></br>
     <!-- content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div id="right" >
     <!-- content goes here -->
  <div>
</div>
<!-- this part stays the same... -->
<div id="footerOpmet">opmeT</div>
<div class="panel">
    <div id="footerAbout">About</div>
    <div id="panel"> 
         <!-- content goes here -->
   </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- don't forget to close all the divs -->
</body>
```

or change your javascript like this:

```
$("#footerAbout").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
});

$("#footerAbout").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Hogan. I originally had it that way, then put a div around both the #footerAbout and #footerPanel, so that they behaved the same way at the same time. I could change it back to what you recommended above, but then everything get's backwards with #panel and #AboutHover triggering the toggle separately. Any other suggestions as to go about this? It works the way I want, except that it's triggered when you hover over the center padding. Thanks again!

Comment: @Keith  I don't know what you mean by backwards.  If you want it to only trigger on the one div then you have to target that div, the center part of the page is part of the div you were targeting that is why it is acting as it is.

Comment: I made a CSS class .panel {} to wrap a div around #aboutOpmet and #panel so they behaved the same way at the same time. In short I only have div class="panel" wrapped only around div id="aboutOpmet" and div id="panel". Any ideas as to why that div class goes up through the whole page? Perhaps I should change a css property like display: ?   Thanks :)

Comment: Because you float the other two divs to the left and right of it.  Just run in Chrome, right click and inspect element and then you can move around your page and see all the elements.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion on using the inspector. I saw that my .panel div ran up through the whole page. I ended up adding clear:both to the CSS. Whether that's the proper way to fix it or not, it works. Thanks again for all your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#footerAbout').hover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
})
```

This could cause a problem, by hiding the `#panel` when mouse is hovered over it

```
var panelTimer;
$('#footerAbout').hover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
}, function(){
    panelTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
    }, 50)
})

$("#panel").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(panelTimer)
})
```

Update

replace

```
$(".panel").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
});

$(".panel").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
});
```

with

```
$('#footerAbout').hover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. For me, hovering over the #footerAbout and the #panel works great. The problem is when you hover over the middle padding (the straight verticle line down the middle of the main content), which triggers the animation as well. I tried your code and tried to delete my corresponding code but couldn't get it to work quite right. Thanks again for your help though, it got me thinking and experimenting.

Comment: @Keith it looks like the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are registered to `$(".panel")` change it to $('#footerAbout') and check

Comment: I registered it to .panel so that #panel and #footerAbout would have the same behavior. Check edit I figured it out, thanks for your input though.